# How can I access the JSON part of the response from Postman batch requests?

Tags: postman, changeset

im using postman to write $batch post requests.

I need to read the response and set variables so the next set of post requests can use as parameters.

As you know the respond from batch request is not parse as pure json so you cannot access the data via normal functions ie pm.response

Any advise how to access the json part of the response ?

I looked online but I couldn’t find any information or it was outdated so I’m not sure if anything changed in the product that might allow parsing